# Laravel 5.2 whereHas column is ambiguous

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am developing a project with `laravel 5.2` . But now I have a problem, In my databases, there are two tables `users` and `comments`. `users` table contains `id, email, username, password, created_at, updated_at`columns. `comments` table contains `id, user_id, content, created_at, updated_at, deleted_at`. Now in my code, I have an `array` which contains some comment id. I want to get `users` who owns these comments. So here is my code:

```
$commentIds = [
    ....
    ...
    ...
];

$users = User::whereHas('comments',function($query)use($commentIds){

    $query->whereIn('id',$commentIds);

});
```

But I get exception said that column id is ambiguous.

Comment: Show us the relationships between `users` and `comments`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$users = User::whereHas('comments',function($query)use($commentIds){
    $query->whereIn('comments.id',$commentIds);
});
```

Will work